# How to extract objects of lat and longi from array and push them into a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object

I've an array of customers and I want to extract only lat and long of each customer and **I want to get this kinda array**

```
latLong=[{lat:123,long:322},{lat:111,long:333},{lat:33,long:11}]
```

here is my array of customers and I want to extract lat longi only from each object and put them into array of objects.

```
  "customers": [
        {
            "id": "5",
            "aname": "Sts Customers",
            "type": "2",
            "address": "house no e 4",
            "area_id": "7",
            "cell_no": "03334488",
            "opn_type": "Debit",
            "opngbl": "2564",
            "lat": "33.7997",
            "longi": "73.04052769999998",
            "company_id": "1",
            "acct_no": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "14",
            "aname": "New Customer",
            "type": "2",
            "address": "house no 4",
            "area_id": "8",
            "cell_no": "7878",
            "opn_type": "Credit",
            "opngbl": "2541",
            "lat": "33.7997",
            "longi": "73.04052769999998",
            "company_id": "1",
            "acct_no": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "15",
            "aname": "one more customer",
            "type": "2",
            "address": "jjkhklj",
            "area_id": "8",
            "cell_no": "8876987",
            "opn_type": "Credit",
            "opngbl": "454",
            "lat": "33.7997",
            "longi": "73.04052769999998",
            "company_id": "1",
            "acct_no": ""
        }
    ],
```

Comment: I would suggest using the map function of the array.  Create a new dictionary at each iteration with only what you need.

Comment: can you send some reference code.

Comment: Another question that may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880884/how-to-move-element-in-nested-array

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```js
const source = {
  customers: [
{
  id: '5',
  aname: 'Sts Customers',
  type: '2',
  address: 'house no e 4',
  area_id: '7',
  cell_no: '03334488',
  opn_type: 'Debit',
  opngbl: '2564',
  lat: '33.7997',
  longi: '73.04052769999998',
  company_id: '1',
  acct_no: '',
},
{
  id: '14',
  aname: 'New Customer',
  type: '2',
  address: 'house no 4',
  area_id: '8',
  cell_no: '7878',
  opn_type: 'Credit',
  opngbl: '2541',
  lat: '33.7997',
  longi: '73.04052769999998',
  company_id: '1',
  acct_no: '',
},
{
  id: '15',
  aname: 'one more customer',
  type: '2',
  address: 'jjkhklj',
  area_id: '8',
  cell_no: '8876987',
  opn_type: 'Credit',
  opngbl: '454',
  lat: '33.7997',
  longi: '73.04052769999998',
  company_id: '1',
  acct_no: '',
},
  ],
};

const result = source.customers.map(({ lat, longi: long }) => ({ lat, long }));

console.log(result);
```

Basically we can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over `source.customers` array.

Then we destructure `customer` object passed to the callback to pick only `lat` and `longi`, renaming `longi` into `long`.

Finally, we return an object containing only key-value pairs we are interested in.

Comment: Thanks Soo Much :)